# Contour plots of a patio-temporal covariance function

Tags: r, time-series, mathematical-statistics, spatio-temporal, spatial-correlation

I would like to plot contour plots of covariance functions in R:

- one for a fitted separable spatio-temporal covariance;
- one for the empirical covariance function,

similarly to Figure 4.4 in Wikle et al [Spatio-Temporal Statistics with R](https://spacetimewithr.org/book).

I understand the theory behind these concepts, I just need help with implementing it to R. Many thanks!